# Automatic domain authentication over https

Tags: iis, authentication, https

I published an ASP.NET website on the web server of my company using HTTPS but I realised that when I want to access the URL I am prompted for credentials, no matter if I am already logged on the domain or not. Actually my problem is that the website publishes a RSS feed that I must enter in another application that does not allow me to provide credentials, therefore it fails. Having a secured connection for this job is a requirement so I cannot publish using HTTP.

How can I automate domain authentication for this URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Internet Explorer, you need to ensure the site is in the 'local intranet' zone (you can do this for your whole company with a suitable GPO).

By default, IE will only automatically authenticate with sites in this zone.

If you are using another browser, then the setting(s) will be different.

For access to your RSS feed, although you need HTTPS, do you also need authentication?  If not, you can disable the authentication requirement within the IIS Management Console for just the specific resource(s) which need to be read.  If you do need the authentication as well as the encrypted channel then the application will have to support automatically sending the users credentials based upon the zone membership of the site.

Comment: Actually I tried to add the site to local intranet settings. Then I was able to access the RSS feed in IE without being prompted. But this problem remains in the application I am using. Maybe this issue is related to a behavior of the application needing this resource. I will investigate in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely sounds like an issue with the application then, the server is acting as expected.